# Inventory all stored procedures in an SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have several SSIS packages for which I need to take an inventory.  Most of these packages contain steps which simply execute a stored procedure.  Is there a way to programmatically or otherwise collect a list all of the stored procedures that are being executed within an SSIS package?

Comment: The name of the stored procedure will exist as text inside the package. I have a script which lists every object in the database, then searches every package for that object to allow me to see what is being used.

Comment: Unless you have someone who does something like Proc = `@[User::SchemaName] + '.' + @[User::DynamicNameHere` The value at rest for DynamicNameHere could be blank but a task within the package actually sets the value of our Variable. Design time is blank, the only way to see what the value is would be to execute

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, care to share?

Comment: @billinkc, no, they're actually all in there.  For some reason, "SQLStatement" has 'execute [StoredProcedureName]', and "IsQueryStoredProcedure" is marked as "False".

Comment: Thank you both for the insanely quick response, btw.  I never knew people on this site were so fast to respond.

Comment: It's only because you've been asking on the wrong tags ;)

Comment: The script I have is composed of a few pieces... a  view that lists every object, and a vbscript that references that view, opens and searches package files, then writes that back to a metadata table. Nowadays you would probably write the whole thing in powershell. If no one else gives you a solid answer I can share it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid am guessing that after six years with no reply then it might be time to share your script?

Comment: After six years the script is long gone and besides any script kiddie would cook it up in python nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire up SQL Server Profiler and run the SSIS packages, ideally against a (otherwise quiet) dev environment.  Here's some steps and further ideas:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/

Comment: Blocked by corporate policy, not an option